# Does Azure AppFabric really support AMQP 1.0?

Tags: amqp, azure-appfabric, azureservicebus

I watched the [AMQP 1.0 presentation by David Ingham](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/AMQP-and-Windows-Azure-Service-Bus), responsible for AMQP at Microsoft, which is about Azure AppFabric's support of AMQP messaging in the cloud. David says AppFabric will support AMQP for the messaging patterns *Queue* and *Pub/Sub*.

Yet when checking documentation on official websites such as http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/how-to-guides/service-bus-queues/ (especially looking at **non-.net** stuff that, according to David's talk is **supposed to connect via AMQP, rather** than MS' proprietary and **SOAP-based SBMP**) there's no mention of AMQP anywhere.

Also, when checking the C# source code David uses for his demo (see page 22 on [his slides](http://daveingham.typepad.com/publications/2011.10.12-AMQPandWindowsAzureServiceBus.pdf)), he uses a `AmqpMessagingFactory` that is nowhere to be googled - except in aforementioned slides.

Btw, the presentation was put on infoq.com on March 15, 2012, rather recently, but the talk was [recorded in October 2011](http://daveingham.typepad.com/blog/2012/04/amqp-and-windows-azure-service-bus-presentation-on-infoq.html), around the time of the AMQP 1.0 spec finalization.

So **did AMQP 1.0 support get ditched** (in favor of `SBMP` perhaps) along the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of this week, Azure Service Bus supports AMQP 1.0. More information is available at: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-amqp-overview/.

Comment: Looks like it's [not released yet](http://nuget.org/packages/ServiceBus.Preview), but that's news indeed.

Answer (score 1):

It says this "Service Bus Queues offer simple first in, first out guaranteed message delivery and supports a range of standard protocols (REST, **AMQP**, WS*) and API’s to put/pull messages on/off a queue."

here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/messaging/

Comment: +1 Thanks Alan. Unfortunately, they neither give a **version number** there, something which is rather [important when it comes to AMQP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12004235/709537), nor does any of the examples on that page in the various languages **use a plain AMQP library so that we can verify**. It's all wrapped up in Azure libraries, one for each supported language. I just checked their `node.js` library sources at https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node , and they seem to be using `REST` there. I need more proof! :)